# Migrar Servidor Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, servidor

Tenemos un *Ubuntu Server 13* físico y queremos hacer una instalación limpia, y migrar todo al nuevo *server 16.04*. ¿Hay alguna herramienta que permita migrar todo de forma fácil? Es decir, que se puedan trasladar:

- Configuraciones de Red.
- Crontab.
- Permisos de Carpetas.
- www.
- Bases de Datos MySql
- Etc.

En caso de que no exista una herramienta, ¿Qué procedimiento sería el correcto para trasladar las carpetas y que la compañía no se vea afectada por dicho procedimiento?

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera de hacer la migración limpia es instalar de nuevo tu Sistema Operativo. Yo te recomendaría que virtualices. La razón es por la flexibilidad. Pero eso no soluciona el tema de migración.
Utiliza KVM que es muy bueno.
Luego crea una maquina virtual Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS e instala tus aplicaciones una por una. Documenta todo el proceso. te va a ayudar para las futuras migraciones. Guarda tus arvhivos de configuración.
Una herramienta mágica que haga todo este proceso no existe. La mejor manera es instarlo de apoco y ver si te funciona todo.

Al finalizar. Utilice el nuevo Server pero no borres el antiguo, hasta que pasen algunas semanas y veas que funciona todo bien.

Answer (score 0):

una forma de hacerlo sin herramienta seria copiar todos los archivos de configuración del servidor viejo al nuevo uno a uno o a base de scripts.

por ejemplo con la red:

- una opcion seria copiar el archivo /etc/network/interfaces[1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=35087).
- crear un script con la configuración de la red[2](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/node/140817#.WBeoFPnhBQI)

Comment: Hola @francesc, por favor, elabora un poco más tu respuesta. Estando como esta ahora parece más un comentario que una respuesta. Hablas de scripts pero, ¿podrías proporcionar algún ejemplo? Creo que con tu respuesta el OP no puede resolver mucho...

Answer (score 0):

Ante todo mil gracias por responder, ya hace unos 20 dias hicimos la migración, basicamente lo que hicimos fue hacer una copia preservando los permisos utilizando "cp -r" las carpetas basicas como: bin, etc, home, usr,var.

Para migrar los usuarios utilizamos la informacion de esta [pagina](http://blog.unreal4u.com/2011/04/migrar-usuarios-linux-de-un-sistema-a-otro/).